# How to extract an n digits number in different forms ( separated by a space) - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract an 8 digit number from different text files. The issue is that there may be or may not a space before and after each digit as below.

Each client places the space however it thinks it makes the number more readable, hence the issue extracting it.

```
 33113306
 33 11 33 06
  3311 3306
```

There may be numbers with more than 8 digits. Those should be ignored. E.g.

```
 33 11 33 06 //the number we need
 28 232392 93293293923 // the number we don't need
```

There is always a space before the first digit.
The 8 digit number we need is placed between 'words' or other characters. However sometimes we have new words on new lines. E.g. 
This is a number

```
 Al : 33 11 33 06 ,
 Another number we don't need 232 2323 232 2, ..sdsad
```

I'm using PHP with preg_match and my old regex fails due this new "feature" to allow the client to define the number in different forms.

```
^(\d){8}$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current input, you can use this:

```
[ ]\K(?<!\d )(?=(?: ?\d){8})(?!(?: ?\d){9})\d[ \d]+\d
```

See what matches and doesn't match in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/17).

Comment: Please have a look at the output [php demo](http://ideone.com/63qFjb). with `preg_match_all` you need to use `$matches[0]` Let me know if you have more questions. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to respond! It would answer my question except it doesn't work on my computer. Is there any extension that I need to install?   Btw I've removed my previous comment as I was prepared  to provide a link with the PHP code running and not working , though i'm not sure if it's due the same reason it doesn't work on my machine.   http://codepad.org/ZptxeAxm

Comment: About my machine : CentOS, PHP 5.3.3 , pcre and pear seem installed

Comment: There are no matches in your latest demo because there is not space char before `12345678`. In the specs, you said there is ALWAYS a space char before the digits, so the regex checks for that. If you no longer want that, I can change it. See [this demo with a space in front](http://ideone.com/0KMYsb)

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove non-numeric characters, and get the first 8 characters of the string:

```
echo substr(preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $string), 0, 8);
```

Comment: Whoa, this is way easier than my answer xD +1

Comment: @Dave you may want to add a comma between 0 and 8. However it still fails miserably. `$string = '9999999999999999 asdsa
12345678
asdasdasd';
$a = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $string);
echo substr($a, 0, 8);`   expected 12345678, received 999...

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function, to filter out everything except numbers, plus and minus. You then use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove the minus and plus (in case there is any):

```
$string=str_replace("+","",str_replace("-","",filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)));
if(strlen($string)!=8){
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work . For example it fails on this  string = '9999999999999999 asdsa
12345678
asdasdasd';

Answer (score 0):

```
[^ \d]+(\d\s*){8}[^ \d]+
```

Try this

Comment: used with `$string = '9999999999999999 asdsa
12345678
asdasdasd';` it outputs `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => asdsa
12345678
asdasdasd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8

        )

)
`