# Go regex - error parsing regexp: invalid escape sequence: `\K`

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to compile a regex so that I can extract an 8 digit number with/without spaces between the digits from a string using Go. For some reasons the compilations fails. What should I repalce K with ?

```
validAcc, err := regexp.Compile(`[ ]\K(?<!\d )(?=(?: ?\d){8})(?!(?: ?\d){9})\d[ \d]+\d`)
if err != nil {
    return
}
```

[Play it here](http://play.golang.org/p/mH6r065gOi)

More code with sample data

```
package main

import "strings"
import "regexp"
import "fmt"

func main() {

    msg := ` 12 34 56 78 //the number we need
 12 3455678 90123455 // the number we don't need`

    acc, err := accFromText(msg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    exAcc := "12345678"
    if acc != exAcc {
        fmt.Printf("expected %v, received %v", exAcc, acc)
    }

    msg = `
More details here
1234567 12345 123456789 asd
12000000000 a number we don't need 
 12 3456 78 //this is the kind of number we need
 12 3455678 90123455 // the number we don't need`

    acc, err = accFromText(msg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    exAcc = "12345678"
    if acc != exAcc {
        fmt.Printf("expected %v, received %v", exAcc, acc)
    }

}

func accFromText(msg string) (accNumber string, err error) {
    validAcc, err := regexp.Compile(`[ ]\K(?<!\d )(?=(?: ?\d){8})(?!(?: ?\d){9})\d[ \d]+\d`)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    accNumber = string(validAcc.Find([]byte(msg)))
    accNumber = strings.Replace(accNumber, " ", "", -1)
    return
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your data so we can figure out a workaround.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish same I would do with php . See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24793414/3780579 .

Comment: @hwnd I've updated the question with a playground snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the [go regexp r2](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/) doesn't support any lookbehind/ahead, could you try a simpler expression first:

```
c, err := regexp.Compile(`\b\d{8}\b`)
```

In your case ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/cDiTYfcKjx)), this would work

```
(\d\d ){4}
validAcc, err := regexp.Compile(`(\d\d ){4}`)
```

Or:

```
(\d\d ?){4} # matches '33 1133 06 Oth'
validAcc, err := regexp.Compile(`(\d\d ?){4}`)
```

Again, I try first a simple regexp, before trying more complex option: it will depend on the data you have to parse.

---

For a more complex case, the regexp alone can help you capture the data in a group, and then you need to **extract the number found** (meaning you ned to add post-processing to your regexp):

```
validAcc, err := regexp.Compile(`[^\d]((\d\d ?){4})[^\d]`)
if err != nil {
    return
}
accNumber = string(validAcc.Find([]byte(msg)))[1:]
accNumber = accNumber[:len(accNumber)-1]
accNumber = strings.Replace(accNumber, " ", "", -1)
```

See [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/O9_hY3fOOR)

Comment: @hey normal: this is for 8 consecutive digits.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if the number is formatted differently (e.g. ` 33 1133 06`. I've updated the playground link http://play.golang.org/p/a8aeRX3fY_

Comment: @hey Again we have no idea of the specifics of your data, I can only imprive as I know more about said data to parse.

Comment: I need to extract an  8 digit number with/without one or more spaces  between the digits from a text. There may be new lines and other characters before the first and after the last digit.

Comment: It seems to match longer numbers ( extract partials ) too http://play.golang.org/p/cnbX6CtPB9 . I need only an 8 digit number. If the number is longer than 8 digits we should 'skip' it.

Comment: seems to work, except it matches also other characters not only digits  http://play.golang.org/p/m_FqqkYXZ5

Comment: @hey that is because you skip the post-processing part: `accNumber = string(validAcc.Find([]byte(msg)))[1:]` and `accNumber = accNumber[:len(accNumber)-1]`! See http://play.golang.org/p/AkSLxGoHng It does work. Re-read my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job (faster: without any regexp need)

```
    package main

    import "fmt"
    import "unicode"
    import "strings"

    func main() {

        msg := ` 12 34 56 78 //the number we need
     12 3455678 90123455 // the number we don't need`

        acc, err := accFromText(msg)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        exAcc := "12345678"
        if acc != exAcc {
            fmt.Printf("expected %v, received %v", exAcc, acc)
        }

        msg = `
    More details here
    1234567 12345 123456789 asd
    12000000000 a number we don't need 
     12 3456 78 //this is the kind of number we need
     12 3455678 90123455 // the number we don't need`

        acc, err = accFromText(msg)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        exAcc = "12345678"
        if acc != exAcc {
            fmt.Printf("expected %v, received %v", exAcc, acc)
        }

    }

    func accFromText(msg string) (accNumber string, err error) {
        // split msg into lines
        lines := strings.FieldsFunc(msg, func(c rune) bool {
            return unicode.IsControl(c)
        })

        // filter numbers
        fn := func(ln string) (num string) {
            for _, c := range []rune(ln) {
                if unicode.IsNumber(c) {
                    num += string(c)
                    // fmt.Println(num)
                } else if !unicode.IsSpace(c) {
                    return num
                }
            }
            return num
        }

        for _, line := range lines {
            num := fn(line)
            if len(num) == 8 {  // 8 numbers in line is the kriterium to accept
                return num, nil
            }
        }
        return "eee", nil  // Note: Change this later; it's only needed to satisfy func calls above
    }
```

http://play.golang.org/p/yVDgDWO9hE

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take two steps:

1) use regexp find all matches: `\d[\d ]+\d`

2) filter out which contains 8 digits

(I don’t think you can do this by a single regex in golang)